# Which preposition is generally used?

Tags: prepositions

•   I hope you weren’t shocked **by / at** what I said.
•   I was shocked **by / at**  what I saw. I’d never seen anything like it before.

Comment: While both are generally similar, shocked by refers to harsher situations than shocked at. E.g., Shocked by the police action; shocked by the announcement, shocked by the action, vs. shocked at his remark; shocked at his approach; shocked  at her reply etc.  May other experts comment more on the differences...

Answer (score 1):

Both are common. A good resource for this sort of information is the Google Ngram Viewer: [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shocked%20at%2C%20shocked%20by&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) it shows *shocked by* overtaking *shocked at* in frequency (within published books scanned into the Google Books database) around 1927, though without ever driving it out of currency.

Difference in meaning seems slight and hard to nail down. One hypothesis might be that *by* suggests that the stimulus is *objectively* shocking, while *at* puts the emphasis more on the subjective response: the same stimulus might *seem* shocking to some but not to others.

Comment: 'By' at least strongly connotes a human agent responsible for the shockingness, and culpability. So 'shocked at what I said' focuses more on the content and may be an attempt to cover up the prior failings of the speaker; 'by' concedes there might have been a teeny bit of impropriety. / 'Shocked by what I saw' again at least hints at personification, responsibility for the outrage lying somewhere. 'At' just references the shocking event / aftermath.

Comment: Per the Oxford *English* Dictionary, @David, this adverbial usage of *plenty* (“As an intensifier”) is *“colloquial* and *regional* (chiefly *U.S.* and *Caribbean*).”

Comment: The less tangled question is whether an intensifier is even wanted there. Out it goes. Thanks on both counts, then, @David.